# The difference between for and over in terms of time

Tags: meaning, word-choice, ambiguity

This is my first question. So please go easy on me if possible.

I can't understand the difference between 'for' and 'over' in terms of time.

For example, What is this difference: 'The birth rate has been increasing over ten years', and 'The birth rate has been increasing for ten years'.

If I can give you another example, what is the difference between 'for centuries' and 'over centuries'.

Maybe this is a very easy question but I can't find out the difference. Please help me.

Comment: If Tony's answer is correct, the interpretation here is that the change (rise) in population is constant! (_Constant_ in the sense of always occurring rather than at an equal rate.)

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I can find out the difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The birth rate has been increasing over ten years* means there may be minor ups & downs when observed in a smaller time window, say an year, but over the span of ten years, there is definitely an increase in birth rate.

*The birth rate has been increasing for ten years* means there is always an increase in birth rate no matter how small the time window is, in the ten years. In mathematics, this is considered as a strictly increasing function of time.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Your answer is very easy to understand. Again, thank you!